# Запуск сторонних приложений через Microsoft Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

я недавно решил попробовать себя в создании приложений в Microsoft Visual Studio. Я хочу создать оконное приложение с определенными кнопками, которые при нажатии на них, будут открывать приложения из системы.
То есть мне нужно понять, как реализовать запуск сторонних приложений после нажатия на кнопку в приложении, созданном в Microsoft Visual Studio.
В интернете я ничего внятного не нашел, очень надеюсь на вашу помощь!!!!

Comment: Для начала, определитесь с языком программирования. Дальше вопрос уже не в запуске "через Microsoft Visual Studio", а в запуске средствами конкретного языка программирования. Для C# и С++ ответ будет значительно различаться.

Comment: Язык программирования С++